# Unresolved import when calling a macro defined in an external crate

Tags: rust, hyper

I am trying to implement a custom HTTP header using [impl_header](http://hyperium.github.io/hyper/hyper/macro.impl_header!.html) macro from hyper crate but it seems it cannot resolve the `hyper::header` module.

Here is my code:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate hyper;
use hyper::header;
struct CustomHeader;
impl_header!(CustomHeader, "value", String);
```

And here is the compiler error:

```
<hyper macros>:11:14: 11:20 error: unresolved import `header::HeaderFormat`. Maybe a missing `extern crate header`?
<hyper macros>:11 Result { use header:: HeaderFormat ; self . fmt_header ( f ) } } }
                               ^~~~~~
<hyper macros>:1:1: 11:67 note: in expansion of impl_header!
lib.rs:4:1: 4:45 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `macro_issue`.
```

Any clue why this happens and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like they haven't used [`$crate`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#the-variable-$crate) when referencing their own modules. Should be a simple fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Renato that this is an issue with hyper, and you should file a bug (or even better a pull request!). If you'd like to work around it for now though, you can re-export `header` as your own:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate hyper;

pub use hyper::header as header;

struct CustomHeader;
impl_header!(CustomHeader, "value", String);

fn main() {}
```

Unfortunately, this simply unlocks a whole new wave of errors that I'll let you figure out!