# Why do I have to expose a macro implementation's 'use' in the client library?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to use a macro I've created in a separate module. With reference to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526180/unresolved-import-when-calling-a-macro-defined-in-an-external-crate), I've imported a macro fine. However it seems that I have

**Update to add macro implementation**

lib.rs

```
#![macro_use]
use std::fmt;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::str;
extern crate libc;

pub enum DbaxError {
    DBAXException(String)
}

 #[macro_export]
macro_rules! dbax_call_test {
    ( $func : expr ) => {
        {
            let call_c_func = unsafe { dbax_function(CString::new($func).unwrap().as_ptr(),0) };
            match unsafe { getErrorCode() as i32 } {
                0 => Ok("Done".to_owned() + $func),
                _ => Err(DbaxError::DBAXException( str::from_utf8(unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(getError()) }.to_bytes()).unwrap().to_string()))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and main.rs in a separate crate

```
// Import macro
#[macro_use] extern crate rustdbax;
// Import implementation details of macro
use rustdbax::*;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    // Call my macro
    dbax_call_test!("DateAdd");
}
```

This works fine, but `use std::*` lines are all part of the implementation in the `lib.rs`.

Why do I have to expose the implementation's 'use' in the client library? Shouldn't rustc as part of it's expansion 'include' whatever was in the `lib.rs`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `macro_rules!` is a bit dumber than you might expect.  It does not, for example, bring imports with it when it expands something.  It's best to think of macro expansion as *mostly* just a dumb copy+paste job.

If you look at any reasonably well-written macro that depends on outside symbols, you'll see things like `::std::result::Result` instead of `Result`.  This is because the macro writer cannot depend on `Result` meaning what they expect in the expansion context.  So the first step is to qualify paths absolutely.

The second thing to know is that every macro expansion gets a `$crate` substitution that is the path to the crate in which the macro was defined.  You can use this to access, for example, `DbaxError` as `$crate::DbaxError`.

Finally, you're in luck; given the expansion, you can cheat a little and just add the `use` items *inside* the expansion:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! dbax_call_test {
    ($func: expr) => {
        {
            use std::ffi::CString;
            use $crate::dbax_function;
            let call_c_func = unsafe { dbax_function(CString::new($func).unwrap().as_ptr(),0) };
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```